# Issue with external links in apk

Tags: apk, phonegap

I used Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 to code my app, and generated an apk using Adobe PhoneGap. It works fine when I am testing, but after the generation of the apk the external links don't work fine. It is not linking to Facebook or Twitter or any of the external websites.

```html
<ul class="social-nav model-3d-0 footer-social w3_agile_social">
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Yobhabusinessdevelopmentservice/"  class="facebook">
            <div class="front"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="back"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/Yobhabusiness/" class="twitter"> twitter</a>
        <div class="front"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="back"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/yobhabusinessdevelopment/" class="instagram">
            <div class="front"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="back"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/yobhasolutions/" class="pinterest">
            <div class="front"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div class="back"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/yobha/" class="linkedin">
</ul>
```

Comment: You have malformed HTML, send it through a validator first.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you did not allow the application to access these links.

You should find what you need in there: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html

If this is not the case, please edit your post by adding your config.xml